# R-Mosaic: Is there a mean.n function?

Tags: r, r-mosaic

is there a ***mean.n*** function (just as in SPSS) in mosaic in R?

I have 3 columns of data (including "NA") and I want a new column to have the means of the 3 data points for each row. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowMeans` might be just what you are looking for. It will return the row-wise mean, make sure to select/subset the right columns.

Here is an example

```r
# Load packages
library(dplyr)

# Example data
ex_data = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = rnorm(10)*2, C = rnorm(10)*5)
ex_data
#>             A          B          C
#> 1   0.2838024 -1.8784902 -2.7519131
#> 2  -0.4090575  1.6457548  6.1643390
#> 3   0.2061454  0.2103105  7.2798434
#> 4  -1.5246471 -0.6071042 -7.2411695
#> 5  -1.0461921 -2.6290405 -1.3840000
#> 6  -1.4802151  1.9323571  5.8539328
#> 7   0.1827485  0.1608848 -0.5157152
#> 8  -0.3006229  2.8650122 -1.4393171
#> 9   2.2981543 -0.2790727  2.6193970
#> 10  1.0495951 -0.9061784 -4.4013859

# Use rowMeans
ex_data$abc_means = rowMeans(x = ex_data[1:3])
ex_data
#>             A          B          C   abc_means
#> 1   0.2838024 -1.8784902 -2.7519131 -1.44886698
#> 2  -0.4090575  1.6457548  6.1643390  2.46701208
#> 3   0.2061454  0.2103105  7.2798434  2.56543308
#> 4  -1.5246471 -0.6071042 -7.2411695 -3.12430691
#> 5  -1.0461921 -2.6290405 -1.3840000 -1.68641084
#> 6  -1.4802151  1.9323571  5.8539328  2.10202491
#> 7   0.1827485  0.1608848 -0.5157152 -0.05736064
#> 8  -0.3006229  2.8650122 -1.4393171  0.37502404
#> 9   2.2981543 -0.2790727  2.6193970  1.54615953
#> 10  1.0495951 -0.9061784 -4.4013859 -1.41932305
```

You mentioned that you have `NA`s in your data, make sure to include `na.rm = TRUE` if appropriate.

<sup>Created on 2021-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! May I ask you real quick what na.rm=TRUe does? Does it remove a row if there is a "NA" in either of the columns?

Comment: `na.rm = TRUE` will ignore the `NA`s in your dataset. If you do `mean(c(1,2,NA))`, it will return `NA`. However, `mean(c(1,2,NA), na.rm = TRUE)` will return ` 1.5 as expected. It will not alter your original data in any sorts.

Comment: So something exactly like Mean.n is not apparent in r? Meaning some function that cancels out specific rows if there are a certain number of "NA's".

Comment: I don't know what `mean.n` is or does, but if you want it to "cancel out the row", i.e. not return a number, don't use `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: Mean.n counts for each row the number of "NA's". And if the number of "NA's" is larger than n the row gets cancelled out. If the number of "NA's" is equal or less, then the "NA's" just get ignored for this row just as in 'na-rm=TRUE'